# SQLSTATE[HY000] [335544721] Unable to complete network request to host "localhost". (SQL: select * from "ADMIN" where "LOGIN" = admin)?

Tags: laravel, firebird

I want to connect the database using a remote server, but I get an error. I use Laravel and Firebird
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXWrL.png)

```
  'connections' => [
        'firebird' => [
            'driver' => 'firebird',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),           
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3050'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'C:\Reports\AVIA.FDB'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'SYSDBA'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'masterkey'),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'UTF8'),
            'engine_version' => '3.0.0',
        ],
```

Comment: In the connection params the host is "localhost", so not very "remote server".
Make sure the Firebird server runs fine on your machine, as it seems it is not installed or stopped or a firewall prevents the connection.

Comment: Your screenshot shows an IP address of 188.130.162.33, which is not the same as localhost. Please make sure you're using the correct hostname, and that the hostname and port is accessible from the machine.